# Bad performance when changing from portrait to landscape

Tags: html, css, image, user-experience

Since some days I've been creating a web page and now I'm facing some issues.

I was doing some tests in order to verify the behaviour on mobile, I noticed that my page were having this strange behaviour when changing from portrait to landscape, It takes around 5 seconds to the page to be displayed properly and this is supposed to happen without delays to provide a good UX.

Also, I just noticed that my menu were having a weird behaviour as well, after pressing the hamburger icon it took around 2-3 seconds for the menu to be displayed.

After doing some tests I think I found issue, I have this css code that adds the social media icons.

```css
.social-media-container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.social {
  float: left;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.mail {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/300&text=Email');
}
.instagram {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/300&text=Instagram');
}
.facebook {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/300&text=Facebook');
}
.youtube {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/300&text=YouTube');
}
.twitter {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/300&text=Twitter');
}
.pinterest {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/300&text=Pinterest');
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

<div class="social-media-container">
  <div class="social mail"></div>
  <div class="social instagram"></div>
  <div class="social facebook"></div>
  <div class="social youtube"></div>
  <div class="social twitter"></div>
  <div class="social pinterest"></div>
</div>
```

After removing this css from my code the page started to work perfectly, I don't see why this should be affecting my menu and delaying the page when changing to landscape mode.

Note: I'm using viewport meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

I will appreciate any helpful answer.

Comment: 5 seconds ? wow! is the size of your background-image really large (like 1920x1080 or above ?). what is the size of the image ?

Comment: I'm noticing that every element with the `background-image` property is also being resized with the styles for the `social` class. I assume that this is causing the browser to resize the images to 50x50 pixels every time there is a page reflow (including toggling the screen orientation). I recommend scaling your images to 50x50 pixels (or you can use the full size images on your page without resizing them).

Comment: Each icon is around 1600px, I was not thinking to leave them at that size, in addition, my backgroud is set to 100%

Comment: Please try performance testing this again with images that are sized so they won't have to be scaled.